# Is there a way to add the sam_account_name of a user in the id_token claims?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are trying to add the `sam_account_name` into the current user's `id_token`. 
It is working well for groups by adding these lines into the application's manifest:

```
"optionalClaims": { "idToken": [{ "name": "groups", "additionalProperties": ["dns_domain_and_sam_account_name"] }] }
```

We did not find something similar for the user. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test it in my side, you can follow the steps below:

**1.** Open your powershell and run the command below to connect to Azure AD.

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

**2.** Create a new policy with this command in powershell:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"onpremisessamaccountname","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name","JwtClaimType":"name"}]}}') -DisplayName "huryTestPolicy" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

**3.** Assign the policy to your service principal:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <your service principal objectId> -RefObjectId <the objectId of the policy created just now>
```

**4.** Please modify the property `acceptMappedClaims` in manifest to `true`.

**5.** Then request for the id token, we can see "onpremisessamaccountname" shows in it.(In my screenshot, I use "**preferredlanguange**" instead of "**onpremisessamaccountname**" because I don't have "onpremisessamaccountname")
[image]

For more information about it, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#claims-mapping-policy-assignment). There are three examples in the tutotial, please refer to the second example(Example: Create and assign a policy to omit the basic claims from tokens issued to a service principal).